# docker multistage build fails on vue.js

Tags: docker, vue.js, docker-compose

This is my dockerFile located at **vDocker/Dockerfile**

```
# build stage
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
COPY ./vDocker/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80 443

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I also have docker-compose located at root directory.

```
version: '3'

services:
  web_client:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./vDocker/Dockerfile
    container_name: web_client
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - /var/www/app/ssl/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - /var/www/app/ssl/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
```

After running docker-compose build,  It gives me the following error:  **Service 'web_client' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/67b326c995a1ce52fb3ee2a792d84ffe9bc403aa5962755a2b89f1ab925a1242/merged/app/dist: no such file or directory**

Any idea why?

Comment: Hi did you solved it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to name the second stage.

How your build looks like depends on how you set it up and I don't know it. But what you can do is:

- run the first stage as a separate Dockerfile
- after the last RUN add `RUN ls -lart` -> this should print the contents of the directory and you can check if the /app/dist really exists

For the rest your code looks good.